# code stopped working after adding condition

Tags: javascript

The code to change the class change of pseudo elements, could not figure out the if statement ...

Guys tell me please, there is a code that works:

```
    $('.dropdownlink').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let lass = $('.dropdownlink').hasClass('dropdownlink--active')
    if (lass) 
      $('.dropdownlink').removeClass('dropdownlink--active');
    else if ($(this).not(this).hasClass('dropdownlink--active')) 
      $('.dropdownlink').removeClass('dropdownlink--active');
      $(this).addClass('dropdownlink--active');
  })
```

I needed to add one more condition at the end, it turned out this:

```
  $('.dropdownlink').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let lass = $('.dropdownlink').hasClass('dropdownlink--active')
    if (lass)
      $('.dropdownlink').removeClass('dropdownlink--active');
    else if ($(this).not(this).hasClass('dropdownlink--active'))
      $('.dropdownlink').removeClass('dropdownlink--active');
      $(this).addClass('dropdownlink--active');
    else if ($(this).hasClass('dropdownlink--active'))
      $(this).removeClass('dropdownlink--active');
  })
```

He began to swear at what the announcement or operator was expected to,
I decided to add curly brackets for each condition:

```
  $('.dropdownlink').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let lass = $('.dropdownlink').hasClass('dropdownlink--active')
    if (lass) {
      $('.dropdownlink').removeClass('dropdownlink--active');
    }
    else if ($(this).not(this).hasClass('dropdownlink--active')) {
      $('.dropdownlink').removeClass('dropdownlink--active');
      $(this).addClass('dropdownlink--active');
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('dropdownlink--active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('dropdownlink--active');
    }
  })
```

stopped cursing, but also completely stopped working, can anyone notice an error, what can I do wrong?

Comment: What exactly does "stopped working" look like? What happened before that doesn't happen now? Or what happens now that didn't happen before?

Comment: Can you add more information, what you want to achive? so we can help

Comment: The line `$(this).addClass('dropdownlink--active');` was originally _outside_ of the condition, even though it was indented. So it should work if you again put it outside.

Comment: (By the way, what is `$(this).not(this)` supposed to do? This will always give you an empty result set, so the whole condition is useless and its body is never executed.)

Comment: `$(this).addClass('dropdownlink--active');` always executed in the first example. ...contributed to the error in the second, because it "orphaned" the last `else if` condition. ...and only executes if the second condition is met in the last example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, the line

```
$(this).addClass('dropdownlink--active');
```

Is executed on both cases (if/else).

Then, your code should look like this:

```
$('.dropdownlink').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let lass = $('.dropdownlink').hasClass('dropdownlink--active')
  if (lass) {
    $('.dropdownlink').removeClass('dropdownlink--active');
    $(this).addClass('dropdownlink--active');
  } else if ($(this).not(this).hasClass('dropdownlink--active')) {
    $('.dropdownlink').removeClass('dropdownlink--active');
    $(this).addClass('dropdownlink--active');
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('dropdownlink--active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('dropdownlink--active');
  }
})
```